# Ajax Error 504 - SQL Stored Procedure saving and returning record

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, web-services, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a SQL Stored Procedure called UpdateKey that saves a record called Key into the Kiosks table of my database (called MyDB) based on record ID, and then returns it, as below:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateKey]
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @key nvarchar(8)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[Kiosks]
    SET session = NEWID(), [key] = @key
    WHERE id = @id;
    SELECT @key AS kioskKey

END
```

I'm trying to call it using Ajax and a service file as below:

Javascript:

```
function updateKeyOnly(index) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Services/Common.svc/UpdateKey/" + kioskList[index].id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success == true) {
                        txtNewKeyDisplay.val(response.keyItem.key); //display new key to user
                        $('#tblKiosks').dataTable().fnClearTable();
                        $('#tblKiosks').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                        loadData();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("updateKeyOnly error" + JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Service (in C#):

```
OperationResponse ICommon.updateKey(string id)
        {
            string newKey = generateKey();
            string result;
            Guid newID;

            if (Guid.TryParse(id, out newID))
            {
                try
                {
                    result = myDB.UpdateKey(newID, newKey).FirstOrDefault();
                    //return new OperationResponse(request.key);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (isDebug() == true)
                    {
                        return new OperationResponse(ex.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new OperationResponse("Error: Database inaccessible.");
                    }
                }

                if (result != null)
                {
                    //return new OperationResponse();
                    resetKeyResponse response = new resetKeyResponse();
                    response.keyItem = new resetKeyItem();

                    response.keyItem.key = result.ToString();

                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new OperationResponse("Error: Key cannot be updated or retrieved.");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                return new OperationResponse("Error: Invalid ID.");
            }

        }
```

From the ICommon.cs:

```
//To Update Kiosk Key
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UpdateKey/{id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        OperationResponse updateKey(string id);
```

Currently my problem is that when I running the Ajax, it gives an Error 504 - Receive Failure according to Fiddler, and on my page itself clicking the button that activates the Ajax causes nothing to apparently happen. Despite that however checking the Kiosks table after that shows that the new key is saved into it after all, it's just that the stored proc can't return it to my webpage. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot - I changed all instances of OperationResponse in updateKey to resetKeyResponse after noticing how inconsistent it was, and then it ran.